# What is an 'elementary, pure language'?

Tags: category-theory

In "Category Theory, A Gentle Introduction", by Peter Smith, one can find the following sentence: "Take $\mathcal{L}$ to be the elementary pure language of categories" - what is a 'language', not to mention a 'elementary pure' one?

Comment: Compare with [Mathematical Logic: Language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Lan)

Comment: I agree this is hard to parse, but I think I know what is meant. "Elementary language" means language in the sense of first-order logic (elementary is often a synonym for first-order in the context of logic). And "pure" means that the only symbols in the language are those needed to axiomatized categories - no extra structure.

Comment: I think my problem is that I have no context - or maybe the wrong contexts. I speak several languages, and I program in a handful, but although I can imagine some sort of mathematical language theory, I have never actually been exposed to any such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary language is another term for a [first-order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). The word "elementary" used in this way is somewhat archaic, but it lives on in terms like [*elementary embedding*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elementary+embedding) (an embedding of one first-order theory into another), [*elementary topos*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos#ElementaryTopos) (a first-order theory whose models are a certain kind of category) [*the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) (a first-order theory roughly equivalent to ZFC), and [*elementary class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class) (a term for the class of all models of a fixed first-order theory).

The author uses the phrase "pure sets" to mean that the basic objects of the theory are sets. By analogy, then, a "pure language of categories" means a theory where the basic objects are categories. The author goes on to describe exactly what he's talking about with two basic sorts of objects and morphisms. There are a few unary and binary operations added in, and some equalities enforced. This *signature* is precisely what's meant by an elementary language (first-order theory).